# MYSQL get the name from another table that is associated with the first table

Tags: php, mysql

I can't figure out why this statement is not working

```
$sql2 = mysql_query("
  SELECT myChurches.id AS id, myChurches.church_name AS church_name 
  FROM myChurches 
  INNER JOIN church_staff 
  ON church_staff.church_id=myChurches.id
  WHERE church_staff.mem_id='$logOptions_id' 
  ORDER BY myChurches.church_name 
  ASC
")

if(mysql_num_rows($sql2) > 0){
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
      $church_id = $row2['id']; 
      $church_name = $row2['church_name'];
        $options .= '<option value="'.$church_id.'">'.$church_name.'</option>';
    }
}
```

Basically I need to find the person's that are staff members of a church from one table and want to get the 'name' of that church FROM the 'myChurches' table. Hopefully that makes sense. Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

Table 1 has a unique id and church_name

Table 2 has unique id, church_id, and mem_id

Comment: Could you please show us the PHP code building this query?

Comment: Could you post your table schema?

Comment: What is mem_id = '$logOptions_id' ? Is table 2 a cross-reference table linking to a third table holding the members' names? @tadman, we do not know the entirety of his script. `$logOptions_id` may be passed through `mysql_real_escape_string()` prior.

Comment: @Zane Bien The user is the $logOptions and the mem_id IE staff member. I don't need their name, I need the churches name they are affiliated with which is the church_id in the staff table

Comment: I see, thanks for updating the post. I wonder is this query processed without an error - and just returns empty set? Can you check what `mysql_error()` returns right after the query code?

Comment: No error, just will not return anything

Comment: Ok. Can you try this query in some external tool (phpMyAdmin or MySQL shell) with some pre-known value instead of $logOptions_id? I'm just trying to narrow the range of error's causes: it's either query itself or PHP code producing this value.

Comment: A-ha. So it's YAPHPB. ) Please var_dump($logOptions_id) somewhere above the query.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12973/discussion-between-raina77ow-and-juan-gonzales)

Comment: No Need, Just got it! The fetch array variable was different from the actual sql variable. Sorry for burdening you. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the fetch array... The variable was different to the actual query variable. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT id, church_name 
  FROM myChurches 
  WHERE id = (SELECT church_id FROM church_staff WHERE mem_id = '$logOptions_id')
```

**EDIT:** this assumes that mem_id **is** unique as you said, **but** church_id should not be unique, unless you are doing something wrong (as it is a foreign key)